# How to copy a file on a remote machine using it credentials with c#

Tags: c#, copy, ip, credentials

I am working on a way to copy files from a local machine to a remote machine (server) using this machine's IP adress and credentials.
I am using C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy file to remote computer using remote admin credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766033/copy-file-to-remote-computer-using-remote-admin-credentials)

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143818/impersonate-access-token-with-backup-and-restore-privilege-for-copying-file-acro